# Which applications use .NET shared framework

Tags: security, asp.net, update

We have a production server running at the premises of our client.
An external security scan was performed on this server indicating the Microsoft ASP.NET Core Shared Framework has some vulnerabilities and need to be upgraded.
How can I check which applications use this shared framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common finding for a component that may exist but there aren't any known web sites or web services running.

Assuming that is the case, and you have port scanned the host to see if there are any listeners, you can download the dotnet-counters tool to track usage and many other data points.

`dotnet-counters ps`

Note that .NET Core is different from previous implementations. It's multi platform, and can be "bin-deployed" without a formal installation. So theoretically there could be multiple independent versions.(Like our Java friend).

Also note there is a separate uninstall tool that exists and may be needed to inventory and manage the various different versions that are known to the system.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-counters#dotnet-counters-ps

https://www.stefangeiger.ch/2020/05/07/dotnet-diagnostics-tools-counters.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used command 'netstat -aon' to search for websites on port 80 and 443. nothing there, then I ran the 'dotnet-counters ps' command giving me serveral candidate executables. These are only the running executables I beleive?